# should I install Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: windows, windows-10, operating-systems, 32-vs-64-bit

my laptop has Intel core duo 2 and 3/4 gigabyte ram and came with windows 7 32bit I checked like guides I found said and seams my laptop is compatible with windows 64bit but I think the manufacturer made the decision of installing windows 32bit for a reason

Comment: No good reason...unless it does not have much installed memory, how much does it have?

Comment: This seems opinion-based to me as written.

Answer (score 1):

Note that to switch up to 64bit you will need to wipe & clean install. You can only upgrade directly if you stay with the 32-bit Win10.
With only 4GB RAM your experience will probably be better if you stick to a 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

as the answer from tetsujin provided, I agree, but if you're looking for an updated operating system, I would use some Linux 64-bit distro that doesn't require much ram, of course, if your not comfortable with that then I would say stay with what you have.

I had a laptop that had 3gb of ram, and I used Linux mint cinnamon with I think 32-bit at the time and I was muuuuch more responsive than any windows-os i had put on it. granted it may use more ram to run the system than desired, but it was enough to watch youtube at the time.